# Naudio opus codec support

Tags: .net, naudio, opus

After failing to find an up-to-date opus (http://opus-codec.org/) .NET wrapper, I came to the realization that (naudio) + (opus) might = (nice to use). The thing is, I've never actually used naudio, even though I have it downloaded and ready-to-go should the need arise.
So, the question is, does naudio support the opus-codec, and if not, is it possible to make support for it, and, if so, what classes must one implement to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAudio provides mechanisms to use codecs that are available through ACM or MFT in Windows. So if there is a version of the opus codec that conforms to either of those interfaces it could be used. Otherwise, custom interop wrappers would need to be created for the codec DLL.

Comment: I don't think opus complies with either AMC or MFT. So I guess I'll have to write a wrapper around the opus API. What NAudio classes/interfaces must I inherit/implement to allow use of the wrapper through NAudio? Obviously, I'll write the opus-wrapper, then an NAudio wrapper around the opus one.

Comment: typically I would create an `OpusFileReader` implementing `WaveStream`. And an `OpusFileWriter` that allows you to dump an `IWaveProvider` directly to an opus file.